# PHP .htaccess modification / extension with additional string matching

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file which i use in a Codeigniter Project :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Currently everything works fine and the rewrite to the controller works as well. E.g:

```
www.abc.com/login --> www.abc.com/index.php?/login
```

What i want to accomplish is that an additional string (kind of security code) is matched by the htaccess and only then the rewrite takes place:

```
www.abc.com/abcdefgh/login --> www.abc.com/index.php?/login
```

I tried all of the following but it just won't work:

```
RewriteRule ^abcdefgh/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/abcdefgh/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^abcdefgh\/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^\/abcdefgh\/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: Access and rewrite.log make more sense than "just won't work".

Comment: @mario Seriously - i did not understand the answer ... can you clarify

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is not a proper problem description - that part is something _you_ need to clarify first of all. And mario was trying to tell you, that checking the server’s access and rerwite log (the latter usually needs to be specifically enabled first) could bring more clarity.

Comment: ok sorry if i offended you guys :-) ..... i enabled the logs and am getting always a 404 ... the only thing that i want is that ... www.test.com/aa/controller/method behaves same as www.test.com/controller/method ....  the "/aa/" part is only in htaccess where it only matches the request and only then passes the (/controller/method) portion on to index.php?$1

Comment: It works fine for me. I used https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=9298d90e-5758-53c0-8e90-881d2a90b58b to test. And I think they wanted you to share the logs here.

Answer (score 1):

first matching rule wins. place your new rules on top of your `RewriteRule` block.

it seems like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` is matched still before you newly added rules.

Comment: Thanks, but i am replacing RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] with the said examples (one by one)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could thread that "security code" in PHP ?

URL : [www.abc.com/login/abcdefgh](http://www.abc.com/login/abcdefgh)

`<?php
    $urlkey = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/',strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') + 1) + 1,strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) - strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')); // seach the 2nd occurence of the '/' in the URL.
    $secretkey = ["abc", "def"]; // could be loaded from a database.

    if (in_array($urlkey, $secretkey)) {
      echo "allowed"; // do allow stuff.
    } else {
      echo "denied"; // do denied stuff... like die();
    }
?>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment - this did come up my mind - but was actually looking to get this to work from the htaccess and thereby finding out where my understanding is faulty. BUT - if there is no suitable answer ill pick your answer as the best :-)

Answer (score 0):

in htaccess you don't have the / in the beginning of the url path

following config works for me

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^abcdefgh/(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

in php you use the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] to get the $1 part, and the query string stays in tact, e.g.

```
http://127.0.0.1/a/b/abcdefgh/a/b/c.php?foo=bar
//calls /var/www/a/b/index.php 

$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] => '/a/b/c.php'
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] => 'foo=bar'
$_GET["foo"] => "bar"
```